# Google maps api error undefine is not a function (map)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following [script](http://jsfiddle.net/0wzme9rh/1/) and I am trying to write some modular JS to keep things tidy and organised. However when I call:

```
weatherAPP.searchCity();
```

in the document.ready I get 'undefined is not a function'.

How can I make the map variable inside 'generateMap' available to 'searchCity'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but you can attach `map` to `this`:

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, mapOptions);
```

instead of

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, mapOptions);
```

and so in searchCity

```
var map = this.map
```

Comment: it seems to work but now I have the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null